# If $f_{n}\left ( x \right )= \frac{x}{\left ( x+ 1 \right )^{n}}$ show that $\sum f_{n}\left ( x \right )$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am stuck trying to solve the problem below.

Suppose $f_{n}:\quad\left [ 1, 2 \right ]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $f_{n}\left ( x \right )= \dfrac{x}{\left ( x+ 1 \right )^{n}}$

Show that $\sum f_{n}\left ( x \right )$ is uniformly convergent on $B= \left [ 1, 2 \right ]$

I think we should use the Weierstrass M-test but I'm having trouble choosing which function to compare it to.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in B$, $$\frac{x}{(x+1)^n} \leq \frac{2}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$